# PHP Radix Sort Algorithm - Type conversion ok?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

This is a function I wrote for a Radix Sort in PHP.
It works for all cases where the array is populated with numbers greater than 0.

```
function radix_sort($arr) {

    // Find the number of passes needed to complete the sort
    $passes = strlen((string)max($arr));
    $buckets = [];

    // Start the passes
    for($i = 1; $i <= $passes; $i++) {
        // Create - reinitialize some buckets
        for ($b = 0; $b <= 9; $b++) {
            $buckets[$b] = [];
        }

        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
            // Drop into the proper bucket based on the significant digit
            $numStr = (string)$arr[$j];
            if (strlen($numStr) < $i) {
                $bucketsIndex = 0;
            } else {
                $bucketsIndex = $numStr[strlen($numStr) - $i];
            }
            array_push($buckets[$bucketsIndex], $arr[$j]);
        }

        // Repopulate our array by pulling out of our buckets
        $k = 0;
        foreach ($buckets as $bucket) {
            foreach ($bucket as $value) {
                $arr[$k] = $value;
                $k++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

I feel like there's too much type converting going on. Is it ok to be doing this? If I wanted to pull the Nth digit from a large number, is there a better way in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert all the value to `string` before the function, and then revert back to `int` at the end:

```
function radix_sort($arr) {

    $arr = array_map ('strval', $arr) ;
    $passes = strlen(max($arr)) ; // Should still work since all values are numeric

    /* Do your stuff... */

    return array_map ('intval', $arr) ; 
}
```

Then in your inner loop you could store the length (I don't really know the complexity of `strlen` in PHP but I assumed it is not `O(1)`):

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
    // Drop into the proper bucket based on the significant digit
    $numStr = $arr[$j];
    $numLen = strlen($numStr) ;
    if ($numLen < $i) {
        $bucketsIndex = 0;
    } else {
        $bucketsIndex = $numStr[$numLen - $i];
    }
    array_push($buckets[$bucketsIndex], $arr[$j]);
}
```

Or you could even (if you have enough memory) use an array to precompute the length:

```
$lengths = array_map ('strlen', $arr) ;
```